# How do I connect to sharepoint syntex library in c# and read files from there?

Tags: sharepoint, c#-6.0

private static void sharepointConnection()
{
try
{
Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect");
const string rootUrl = "";
const string reqUrl = "";
const string pwd = "";
const string username = "";

```
            SecureString securestring = new SecureString();
            pwd.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(s => securestring.AppendChar(s));


            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(reqUrl);
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securestring);

            
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSOM code in below format after authentication:

```
public static List<ListItem> GetAllDocumentsInaLibrary()
{
    List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
    string sitrUrl = "https://spotenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite";
    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(sitrUrl))
    {
        //ctx.Credentials = Your Credentials
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web, a => a.Lists);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
        ListItemCollectionPosition position = null;
        // Page Size: 100
        int rowLimit = 100;
        var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
            <Query>
                <OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='ID'/></OrderBy>
            </Query>
            <ViewFields>
                <FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><FieldRef Name='Editor' />
            </ViewFields>
            <RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>" + rowLimit + "</RowLimit></View>";
        do
        {
            ListItemCollection listItems = null;
            camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
            listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            ctx.Load(listItems);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            position = listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
            items.AddRange(listItems.ToList());
        }
        while (position != null);
    }           
    return items;
}
```

**References**:

1. [Get all files from a SharePoint Document Library using CSOM](https://morgantechspace.com/2017/08/get-all-files-from-sharepoint-document-library-csom.html)
2. [Download all files from Sharepoint Online Document Library using C# CSOM](https://sharepointmates.com/2019/10/22/download-all-files-from-sharepoint-online-document-library-using-c-csom/)